# What "How about" subject predicate object is？

Tags: subjects, predicate

As we all know, the sentence "*How about walking in the park?*" is perfectly viable.

But where is the subject of this sentence?

And how can we define its subject, predicate, and object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use [How about](https://www.lexico.com/definition/how_about) to make a suggestion or to ask for information. [More examples [here](https://www.use-in-a-sentence.com/a-words/collocation-1/how-about.htm).] It is often used in  [informal](https://www.lexico.com/definition/informal) (definition 2) English: when speaking or writing to our friends and family, for example.

In this conversation between two friends, *how about* is used to make a suggestion:

> Person A: How about a pizza?
>  Person B: Not hungry.
>  Person A:
> A game of tennis?
>  Person B: Too hot. How about walking in the park?
>  Person A: OK. And *then* pizza.

Here it is used to ask for information:

> Person A: You don't like swimming?
>  Person B: No.
>  Person A: Or jogging?
>  Person B: No.
> Person A:  How about walking in the park?
>  Person B: No. I prefer lying in bed drinking beer.

Comment: Thank you all. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete sentence in the traditional sense. In other words, it does not contain both a complete subject and a complete predicate.

It is possible to construe this "sentence" as a prepositional phrase:

> *how about*: phrasal preposition
> *walking*: gerund functioning as the object of the preposition
> *in the park*: prepositional phrase modifying "walking"

Of course, others may parse it differently.